Set display time for interstitial ads using applovin max
I want to set the display time duration of the first interstitial ad, then set another time duration for the succeeding ads.
How can I do that?
I am a beginner so please be kind ‍♀️
I tried placing getInsAdDuration() inside onAdDisplayedCallback but it didnt work.
final String _interstitial_ad_unit_id = Platform.isAndroid ? "ANDROID_INTER_AD_UNIT_ID" : "IOS_INTER_AD_UNIT_ID";

const int _maxExponentialRetryCount = 6;

var _interstitialRetryAttempt = 0;

bool _adFirstLaunch = true;

void initializeInterstitialAds() {

    AppLovinMAX.setInterstitialListener(InterstitialListener(
        onAdLoadedCallback: (ad) {
            // Interstitial ad is ready to show. AppLovinMAX.isInterstitialReady(_interstitial_ad_unit_id) now returns 'true'
            print('Interstitial ad loaded from ' + ad.networkName);

            // Reset retry attempt
            _interstitialRetryAttempt = 0;
AppLovinMAX.showInterstitial(_interstitial_ad_unit_id);
        },
        onAdLoadFailedCallback: (adUnitId, error) {
            // Interstitial ad failed to load
            // AppLovin recommends that you retry with exponentially higher delays up to a maximum delay (in this case 64 seconds)
            _interstitialRetryAttempt = _interstitialRetryAttempt + 1;

            if (_interstitialRetryAttempt > _maxExponentialRetryCount) return;

            int retryDelay = pow(2, min(_maxExponentialRetryCount, _interstitialRetryAttempt)).toInt();

            print('Interstitial ad failed to load with code ' + error.code.toString() + ' - retrying in ' + retryDelay.toString() + 's');

            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: retryDelay * 1000), () {
                AppLovinMAX.loadInterstitial(_interstitial_ad_unit_id);
            });
        },
        onAdDisplayedCallback: (ad) {
        getInsAdDuration();
        },
        onAdDisplayFailedCallback: (ad, error) {
            ⋮
        },
        onAdClickedCallback: (ad) {
            ⋮
        },
        onAdHiddenCallback: (ad) {
            ⋮
        },
    ));

    // Load the first interstitial
    AppLovinMAX.loadInterstitial(_interstitial_ad_unit_id);
}

Future<void> getInsAdDuration() async {
    if (_adFirstLaunch) {
      Duration(
          seconds: int.parse(FirebaseService().remoteConfig.insLogic1)
      );
      _adFirstLaunch = false;
    } else if  (!_insFirstLaunch) {
      Duration(
          seconds: int.parse(FirebaseService().remoteConfig.insLogic2)
      );
    }
  }

